# What is overflow encountered in double_scalars?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, overflow

I'm trying to implement gradient descent in Simple linear regression. Whenever I run the code, I get the error

**The code i am using is this:**

```
def get_data(df, feature, predict):
    X = df[feature]
    Y = df[predict]

    X = np.float64(X)
    Y = np.float64(Y)

    return X, Y


def average(X, Y, b, m, length):
    temp1 = 0
    temp2 = 0

    for i in range(length):
        temp1 += (b + m * X[i]) - Y[i]
        temp2 += ((b + m * X[i]) - Y[i]) * X[i]

    return temp1 / float(length), temp2 / float(length)


def gradient_descent(b, m, alpha, length, num_iterations, X, Y):
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        temp1, temp2 = average(X, Y, b, m, length)

        b_temp = b - alpha * temp1
        m_temp = m - alpha * temp2

        b = b_temp
        m = m_temp

    return b, m


def run(b, m, alpha, feature, predict, df, num_iterations):
    X, Y = get_data(df, feature, predict)

    length = np.alen(X)

    final_b, final_m = gradient(b, m, alpha, length, num_iterations, X, Y)

    return final_b, final_m


b, m = run(0, 0, 0.05, 'sqft_living', 'price', df, 1000)
```

**The error it gives my is this:**

> /Users/*****/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:15:
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars   from
>   ipykernel import kernelapp as app
>   /Users/*****/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:25:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars.

I'm not able to identify which part of the code is causing the error. I tried to convert numpy array to float64 also my code is not running into Divide by Zero Error. Can someone identify the error? Also, How can it be rectified?

Comment: People could probably help better if you created a self-contained example (no external data, all imports, minimal code) - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that if you use numpy floats you will not run into a `ZeroDivisonError` but you get `nan` or `inf` instead.

Comment: I think your gradient descent diverges. Try lowering your learning rate, alpha.